# Getting Facebook Public Profile URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, nokogiri

I'm building a feature in my web service to let people enter their Facebook URL into a field. Because few people know their FB user names or public profile URLs, I'd like to provide an interface to assist.

In brief: is there a way to get a list of matching users's public URLs by providing a name alone?

I have tried examining the Facebook Open Graph API; this appears to require knowing the user ID of the person, or the user ID.

I have tried using Mechanize and Nokogiri to automate the process, logging into Facebook as myself and accessing the search feature (http://facebooks.com/search/results.php?q=Person%20Name), but it's not returning any data when attempted this way. I suspect Facebook is using some kind of joojoo to keep me out that way.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done additional research, it appears to not be possible to get a user's public profile page without their permission. Hooray for Facebook privacy settings, I guess.

However, getting an access token is easier than I imagined it would be. Facebook offers an [example on their site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) for getting user permission to access their account, *implemented entirely on the client side*. Nice and easy; the access token is returned in the URL.

The only downside here is you have to create an application on Facebook, at http://developers.facebook.com/apps. For my purposes, the "Website with Facebook Login" was the application type.

From that point, you can use that token to interrogate the Graph API with ease, as both Warpling and complex857 have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

With a valid access token, you should be able to query `https://graph.facebook.com/me/` to get their ID, name, and **public URL** (Here's an example using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me)).

Comment: My understanding is that you get an access token from a user via an OAuth process. Assuming I have a user's OAuth access, I imagine getting their public URL is easy. But I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. It's interesting to me that you need a token to access the graph for /me, but accessing /yourname is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a search endpoint in the graph API, unfortunately it requires valid user access token.

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<name>&type=user&access_token=<user access token>`

However it could be yours even, by getting a long living access token it would work for 60 at most, but it's probably a bad idea.

The type could be `user`, `post`, `event`, `group`, `page`.

Comment: I don't have the user ID. I would just have a name.

Comment: Oh, i guess i totally missed the point of the question. Updated the answer, still needs user access token.